# AEM: Error logs

Tags: aem

I have some different errors

in blueprint

> com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.commands.RolloutCommand Error during roll-out.
>   com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMException: javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException:
>   OakState0001: Unresolved conflicts in /content/sites/.../jcr:content

Rollout:

> POST /bin/wcmcommand HTTP/1.1]
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate Attempted to
>   perform getValue while thread pool-7-thread-14-(cq/wcm/msm/job/pageEvent) was concurrently writing to this
>   session. Blocked until the other thread finished using this session.
>   Please review your code to avoid concurrent use of a session.

For all pages:

> com.day.cq.wcm.commons.ReferenceSearch Adjusted property
>   /content/sites/.../jcr:content/header/reqInfoURL.

anyone can help? What accounts for these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: Can you please specify a bit more information? What user are you using when trying to roll-out. What is the structure of the pages you are trying to roll-out? Is the MSM configuration set properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Old question so answering here in case someone is looking for a solution to same problem as I did.

This issue was due to problems in earlier version of AEM 6.0 and has been addressed in AEM 6.0 SP3 and later versions of the product. It has nothing to do with multiple sessions on the locked page but rather a race condition in the same code.